# How can I avoid duplicates accross multiple columns in access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

My question is pretty simple, yet I am unable to find the answer I need. I have an access database with a table called coaches. I have another table called teams, which can have a coach and assistant coach. I need to be able to allow no duplicates across the "Coach" and "Assistant Coach" Fields. Coaches can be both head coaches or assistant coaches, so I cannot have a coach be both for different teams.

Comment: Can a coach be a head coach or assistant coach of more than one team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a coach can only be assigned to one role for one team, then add the *team* and *role* to the `coaches` table.

This will guarantee that a coach can only be associated with a single team in a single role.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make it work better by adding the team and role fields to the coaches' database and adding a multiple-field index with unique indexes across both fields. This ensured that there can only be one coach and assistant coach for each team!